# CSS overrides elements a with b

Tags: css, inheritance

in my CSS I have

```
.footer a {color :red}
.footer b {color :green}
```

in code:  `<b><a> ... </a></b> .... <a>..</a>`

It shows all in color red.
I want to specify different  and `<a>..</a>` colors, but `<a>` overrides `<b>` ..How should I proceed?

Comment: It would help if you showed your HTML.

Comment: Tomasusa - use the code formatting option (1010 icon) to include HTML code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<b><a> ... </a></b> .... <a>..</a>
```

In other words, the bold tag contains an a tag. Text within the a tag is, according to the CSS, red. This overrides the styling for the b tag.

Try this CSS:

```
.footer a {color :red}
.footer b a {color :green} /* Apply rules to a tags within bold tags */
```

On the other hand, you say that everything is green, when I'd expect everything to be red. This suggests an HTML error. Run the HTML through the W3C Validator.

Answer (score 2):

```
.footer b {color :green}
.footer a {color :red}
```

If you declare like above, the second definition will override the first.

---

Note: However, if you only want <a> which are inside (children of) <b>, then you should use

```
.footer b a {color :red}
```

Answer (score 1):

Note that .footer a essentially means "All Anchor elements in an element with class footer" while .footer b means "All bold elements in an element with class footer". If your HTML is something like this:

```
<div class="footer">
<b>Lorem Ipsum Dolor</b>
</div>
```

It would make sense that it is turning green.

Comment: Where are the RTE controls...cant style my post! Edit: Thanks bdukes!

Answer (score 1):

The `a` element will be red unless you style it differently. Since it has a style it isn't going to `inherit`.

```
.footer a {color :red}
.footer b,
.footer b a {color :green}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
.footer b,
.footer b * {
    color: green
}
```

The selector `.footer b *` additionally selects all descendant elements of `b`.

Answer (score 0):

Also, use Firebug to debug what is happening to your CSS. It's free, easy to install and extremely helpful:

http://getfirebug.com/